# Append elements at the end of each line into a file

Tags: c, file

I want to append elements into a file line by line, not the end of the file. 
I wrote this code, but the result was that I could only append elements at the end of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static const char filename[] = "m.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r+a");
    char *a = "ok";

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[128];         /* or other suitable maximum line size */

        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)  /* read a line */
        {
            fputs(a, file);     /* write the line */
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        perror(filename);       /* why didn't the file open? */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some answers have mentioned buffer.
I am a little confused with the buffer here. Does it mean I have to read more than one line into memory and then modify them? And is buffer the same as BufferedReader class in Java?

Comment: You can't do that because you are overwriting the contents of the file, use a buffer and replace the whole file content.

Comment: Removed mentions of C++ as that's not relevant to the code.

Comment: It's not clear what you are wanting to do. What are you trying to append and where are you trying to append it to if not the end? Perhaps an example of intended input and output would help.

Comment: I am a little confused with the buffer here. Does it mean I have to read more than one line into memory and then modify them? And is buffer the same as BufferedReader class in Java? @lurker

Comment: For example, the first line is 'I am '; the second line is "He is" in a file, and I want to change it into first line "I am ok" the second line is "he is ok"@kaylum

Comment: One method is to read up to the end of a line whilst writing that to the output file. Then when reach the end of a line, write your insert text to the output, holding off on reading the input, then resume reading the input until the next end if line, writing it to the output. That's basically your loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Does it mean the buffer refers to my temporary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read each line one at a time, modify it as you see fit, and then rewrite the whole line *to a new file*. Then when you have read the whole file you rename the new file as the old file.

***Or*** you read the whole file into memory, for example into an array, one line per element of the array, modify the lines, and overwrite the contents of the file.

The problem with modifying a variable-length text file is that you nee4d to shift all data after the insertion point, which is not easy to do in a file. That's why it's easier to read the whole file into memory and do the modifications there, or use a temporary file that you then rename.

Comment: Using a temporary file is way safer. In the case of a critical bug at the worst moment your file should at least be in the temporary file. With the overwriting from memory method you can lose the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

Files are not stored as an array of lines you can append to and manipulate at will, they are one big chunk of data you interpret. So if you were to do such a thing, you'd overwrite the rest of the file that follows your current line.

What you have to do is re-write at least the entire rest of the file whenever you do this. You can do that easily using a buffer.

Lines in files are just formatting and logical points marked by the newline character.

Comment: Thanks for your help!